# How to properly link an Arduino and its sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, communication

To finalize a prototype, I would like to have a proper structure containing the arduino (uno here), its shields and its sensors. I would like the sensors to be soldered to the arduino+shields block, but the sensors were sold on a small separate PCB ([example](http://a.co/aeGIzCB)).

**What is the recommended method to have a strong, clean link between the two ?**

Answer (score 2):

You could solder those modules to a prototype shield.  If you replace the header with a right-angle one (or even just bend the pins on the existing one) you could even mount it vertically to save space.

- Prototype shield:

[image]

- Right-angled headers:

[image]

Comment: This sounds right. I would be glad if you could illustrate with pictures so that it is perfectly clear, though. Thank you

Comment: I tried to find a picture online but couldn't. You may be the first to do it :)

Comment: A prototype shield has a matrix of holes like a breadboard - except you solder them. The breakout board has pins. The pins go in the holes, and you solder it. Then you solder wires between those soldered pins and the Arduino header pins. If you want more than one module and the pins are only on one side, then use right angled pins so the breakout board sticks up in the air.

Comment: In effect treat the breakout board like any other component. It's just a little larger than most.

Comment: You can create a pretty good quality DIY "prototype shield" (shields are expensive) like here https://startingelectronics.org/projects/arduino-projects/arduino-tiny-stripboard-shield/